# No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'

Tags: android, aapt

When i am creating new Android project **appcompat_v7**  is giving error

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name                 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.    styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line 79 Android AAPT Problem
```

But my android SDK is uptodate ( Android SDK Tools 23.0.5, Android 5.0).

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

u should have 2 folders in your res file.
1) values (which is there by default)
2) Create another folder in res and name it values-21

Now in values folder, dont use any Material theme component. Because that folder will be used for devices running on older SDKs.
Colpy the contents of values folder in values-21 folder and change desired themes into Material themes. This folder will be used in devices which support Material Design SDKs.

Comment: another solution is to set compile , target and min SDK to 21 (andriod-L). But then, your app will only run on devices with android-L